# jQuery Validation remote with invalid variable name: How to fix?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using [remote](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) validation with jQuery Validation.

I'm trying to call my server side code in MVC but the problem is that my variable is in a nested class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public State HouseState {get;set;}
}

public class State
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In my *.cshtml I have this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HouseState.Name, new { placeholder = "State Name"})
```

I'm adding validation with this:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("verify", verify);

    $('#HouseState_Name').rules('add', {
        verify: true,
        remote: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Validate")',
        messages: { verify: "No!" }
    });
```

In this case it will generate a GET request like this:

```
http://localhost/Home/Validate?HouseState.Name=CA
```

The problem is that it expect my variable in the server be `House.Name` witch is an invalid variable name in C#.

Is there a way I could customize this variable in the client or make an alias for the variable in the server? I've tried use `FormCollection` and it worked but is far from perfect.

```
public JsonResult Validate(FormCollection form)
{
    ...
}
```

I wanted some way to it work like this:

```
public JsonResult Validate(string stateName)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` to effectively 'strip' the prefix.

```
public JsonResult Validate([Bind(Prefix="HouseState.Name")]string Name)
```

so `name="HouseState.Name"` becomes just `Name` when binding

Comment: Nice. It did the trick. The problem now is that actually it's a DateTime variable and it's getting wrong culture just here. But it's another problem. Thanks.