# MVC remote validation with complex model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Lets's say I have this validation method in the controller `DefaultsController` :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult DefaultNameValidation(string DefaultName)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My view model is :

```
public class DefaultsViewModel
{       
    public DefaultCreationModel DefaultCreationModel { get;set;}
}
public class DefaultCreationModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le nom du défaut est obligatoire.")]
    [Remote("DefaultNameValidation", "Defaults")]
    public string DefaultName { get; set; }
}
```

And how the input field is generated :

```
 <div class="row m-2">
     <span class="mr-2 my-auto font-weight-bold">Nom du nouveau défaut </span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DefaultCreationModel.DefaultName)
 </div>
```

In this case, when the validation is performed, the string `DefaultName` passed to the controller is null.

But if I do (string `DefaultName` directly in the main model) :

```
public class DefaultsViewModel
{       
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le nom du défaut est obligatoire.")]
    [Remote("DefaultNameValidation", "Defaults")]
    public string DefaultName { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is fine.

How to make it works as it is in the first case ? (because it'a a big view and I need to keep it as clear as possible without mixing intentions)

Comment: You need to show your view and how you generate the input for `DefaultName`, but best guess is [jQuery Validation remote with invalid variable name: How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839202/jquery-validation-remote-with-invalid-variable-name-how-to-fix) will solve your problem (in your case - `[Bind(Prefix="DefaultCreationModel.DefaultName")]`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, the best guess is the right one. With the prefix it works. Could you post an answer so that I can solve this trouble.

Comment: You still have not edited the question :) (but I will dupe it anyway)